# How to add .hgignore to my Mercurial folder?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, filesystems

I'm learning to use Mercurial, and its learning curve is pretty straightforward. But one of my problem is, I can't add the .hgignore file to Mercurial folder. Windows (7) does not allow me to do this, and when I run the command

> hg add .hgignore

, it returns error:

> the system cannot find the specified
>   file.

How can I create/add this file?

Comment: [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) adds it automatically when creating a repository.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Execute

`touch .hgignore`

or

`echo "" > .hgignore`

in the needed directory

Answer (score 8):

Create it from the command line

```
echo syntax: glob > .hgignore
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add it to Mercurial directory. You should place `.hgignore` to repository's root directory.

> The Mercurial system uses a file called .hgignore in the root directory of a repository to control its behavior when it searches for files that it is not currently tracking

You also can set up global .hgignore files:

> In addition, a Mercurial configuration file can reference a set of per-user or global ignore files. See the hgrc(5) man page for details of how to configure these files. Look for the "ignore" entry in the "ui" section.

And there you can see instructions to define ignore file in mercurial.ini (or hgrc) file:

> ignore
>   A file to read per-user ignore patterns from. This file should be in the same format as a repository-wide .hgignore file. This option supports hook syntax, so if you want to specify multiple ignore files, you can do so by setting something like ignore.other = ~/.hgignore2. For details of the ignore file format, see the hgignore(5) man page.

Comment: I failed to mention that "Mercurial folder" is the .hg folder in my source code

Comment: I understood that. I say that .hgignore should be put not to .hg folder, it should be put to repository root folder, i.e. it should be placed in the same folder where your source code is.